# Set values to zero in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm creating the SMAPE loss function in tensorflow and i need to set to 0 the values of the tensor diff before computing the reduce mean. Here is my code but it doesn't work:

```
function loss(yHat, y):
     denominator = (tf.abs(yhat) + np.abs(y))/2.0
     diff = tf.div(tf.abs(yhat - y),denominator)
     other_variable = tf.get_variable("other_variable",
                                 dtype=tf.float32, 
                                 initializer= diff)
     comp = tf.equal(denominator, 0)
     cond_diff = tf.scatter_update(other_variable, comp, 0)
return tf.reduce_mean(cond_diff)
```

it gives me this error

> ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("div_49:0", dtype=float32)

Answer (score 0):

Just mask your `diff` instead of creating another variable.

```
mask = tf.where(denominator == 0, tf.ones_like(denominator), tf.zeros_like(denominator))

return tf.reduce_mean(tf.multiply(diff,mask))
```